# Making angular app work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs

Following the instructions [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), I can get a simple angularJS app working in IE.

However, I'm struggling with the constraint that you need to add `id='ng-app' ng-app='some-module'` to the root (html) element. The Docs state:

"add id="ng-app" to the root element in conjunction with ng-app attribute"

```
<!doctype html> 
    <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app"
ng-app="optionalModuleName">   
    ... 
    </html>
```

But how does that work if my app has multiple modules - which is surely the commonplace? In my scenario, I've got a table module that deals with a pagable table control, and I've just created a module to handle displaying country flags.

Does this restriction mean that I can only have a single module (uberModule) with everything defined in there? Seems a bit rubbish, or am I missing something?

Disclaimer: I'm a angular noob so it could be that I'm just doing something very wrong

Comment: How many `ng-app` attributes are you going to have on the page?  More than one?

Comment: I suppose so - I could have a page that has both the table (in tableModule) and the country flag. Are you saying that in angular I should only use one per page?

Comment: Typically, (in a SPA) there is only one per page, because `ng-app` defines a `$rootScope`.  Usually, you would use `ng-include` or routing to then swap out UI components inside a single `ng-app`.

Comment: You can use multiple per page, have a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap - I used this method multiple times and have not experienced any problems in IE(8)

Comment: @DavinTryon So if I have ng-app in my HTML element set to my table module, and I want to use my countryflag module (which contains a directive and a controller), how could I do that?

Comment: @Florian So you're saying I should use `angular.module('myApp', []);` to manually load up my modules manually on the page?

Comment: In that configuration, bootstrapping seems to be your best option.  This would require multiple `ng-app`.  @Florian seems to have used this successfully with IE.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how the bootstrapping would work - just tried removing all ng-app attributes and adding the code `angular.element(document).ready(function() {
         angular.module('myApp', []);
         angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
       });` but that errors - says it can't find the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, there is only a single `ng-app` on an html document as described [in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp):

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an application. Only one ngApp
>   directive can be used per HTML document. The directive designates the
>   root of the application and is typically placed at the root of the
>   page.
>
> The first ngApp found in the document will be auto-bootstrapped. To
>   use multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually
>   bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap. Applications cannot be nested.

Of course, if you only have a single `ng-app`, then there is no problem having a single `id` attribute set to the value "ng-app".

Although, as mentioned above, you can use [bootstrapping](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) to manage multiple `ng-app` on a page. Since, bootstrapping manually doesn't require an `ng-app` attribute to be placed on the page, there should be no `id` attribute issue.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, because I ended up following your advice and making sure I was always using just one ng-app per page. Took a little bit of refactoring, but I ended up with one module that pulled dependencies from other modules and this seemed to work OK

Comment: Yes, I think you will be ok with this.  Kind of like pulling in different namespaces for functionality that your app needs.